# MATLAB Find row in cellular array containing two variables

Tags: matlab, find, cell

I am trying to find the row in the cell array that contains (for example) the value 6 and string Steel (see matrix `C` at bottom of question). I understand I can use the following:

```
>> find(strcmp(C, 'Steel'))

ans =

    11
    14
    17
```

Which gives me the general index, if I subtract 9 (length of matrix) I get rows `2, 5, 8`. Great. And to find the value 6:

```
>> find([C{:}] == 6)

ans =

     1     2     3
```

Super. Any idea how I go about combing this information to find the 2nd row? I would like to extract the value C{2,3} essentially. I am given the value (6) and the material (Steel), and from above I know to look in the second row; but how can I pass this automatically?

```
C = {6, 'Concrete',  0.37,   0.33;
     6, 'Steel',     0.1,    0.1;
     6, 'Lead',      0.057,  0.057;
     10, 'Concrete', 0.41,   0.37;
     10, 'Steel',    0.11,   0.11;
     10, 'Lead',     0.057,  0.057;
     15, 'Concrete', 0.44,   0.41;
     15, 'Steel',    0.11,   0.11;
     15, 'Lead',     0.057,  0.057};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll find the indexes with `6` at the first column:

```
index1 = find(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x, 6), C(:,1), 'UniformOutput', 0)));
```

Now, the indexes with 'Steel' at the second column:

```
index2 = find(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,'Steel'), C(:,2), 'UniformOutput', 0)));
```

Finally, their intersection:

```
index = intersect(index1, index2);
```

So `C(index, :)` is the line you want.

Note that if more lines would satisfy these two conditions, `index` would be a vector, and `C(index, :)` would be an `n x 4` cell array.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that the material is always in the second column and the number always in the first? If so use this information and search only in these columns:
`rows_six=cell2mat(C(:,1))` and `rows_steel=strcmpi(C(:,2),'steel')`. To get the rows with 6 and steel, use `C(rows_six&rows_steel,:)`